# remove Bootable CD from VM programatically

Tags: automation, esx

I am doing automation of installation of OS(Custom Linux) on a VM on ESXi by plugging in bootable iso of the OS. After the installation of the OS is done, a restart is required of the VM to proceed with the normal OS launch.

I need to automate this. The problem is if the bootable CD is plugged in, instead of booting from the HDD, the system boots from the CD. Is there any way to eject the CD from the VM programatically? or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If the OS is linux(as was my case), one can eject the CD using something like:

eject -T /dev/sr0